# Predicting text in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp

[image]

I have DataFrame like this in the image. I have to predict "selected_text" column on the basis of text and sentiment columns. How can I train the model on these 2 columns to further predict the "selected_text" column?

Comment: Are you asking algorithms that gives you selected_text based on text and sentiment? It is hard to say because I cannot know what selected_text should be. Maybe some NLP algorithms help you.

Comment: Hi @dmjy. Thanks for your response. I have seen various NLP algorithms but they only explains text classification. I am trying to predict the text from 2 inputs.

Comment: I cannot give you a specific algorithm, but it depends on how to use algorithms. For example, there should be some algorithms that tell you each word is positive or negative. If sentiment is positive, then selected_text may be one of the positive words in text.

Comment: @dmjy That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the textID column is irrelevant. But you could perhaps assign a value to the sentiment column (1 for positive, 0 for negative.) You could then create a one-hot encoding for each word in the selected column using the following code:

```
one_hot = []
current_bit = 1
current_one_hot_value = ""
for word in <EVERY_WORD_MENTIONED>:
    current_one_hot_value += bin(current_bit)[2:]
    for x in range(0,<HOW_MANY_WORDS> - len(current_one_hot_value)):
        current_one_hot_value += "0"
    one_hot.append(current_one_hot_value)
    current_one_hot_value = ""
    current_bit  = current_bit << 1

true_one_hot = []
one_hot_str = []
for encoding in one_hot:
    for bit in encoding:
        one_hot_str.append(int(bit))
    true_one_hot.append(one_hot_str)
    one_hot_str = []
```

For example, if you had the words "hello", "hi" and "bye", they would become:
001, 010 and 100.

You could then do some preprocessing on the actual text part of the dataframe, and put it into a neural network such as the one on the Keras website (with a large amount of modification):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import io

path = "<YOUR TEXT FILE OF TEXT HERE>"
with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()
print('corpus length:', len(text))

chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
print('total chars:', len(chars))
char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# cut the text in semi-redundant sequences of maxlen characters
maxlen = 40
step = 3
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])
print('nb sequences:', len(sentences))

print('Vectorization...')
x = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(chars)), dtype=np.bool)
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
        x[i, t, char_indices[char]] = 1
    y[i, char_indices[next_chars[i]]] = 1


# build the model: a single LSTM
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))
model.add(Dense(len(chars), activation='softmax'))

optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)


def sample(preds, temperature=1.0):
    # helper function to sample an index from a probability array
    preds = np.asarray(preds).astype('float64')
    preds = np.log(preds) / temperature
    exp_preds = np.exp(preds)
    preds = exp_preds / np.sum(exp_preds)
    probas = np.random.multinomial(1, preds, 1)
    return np.argmax(probas)


def on_epoch_end(epoch, _):
    # Function invoked at end of each epoch. Prints generated text.
    print()
    print('----- Generating text after Epoch: %d' % epoch)

    start_index = random.randint(0, len(text) - maxlen - 1)
    for diversity in [0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.2]:
        print('----- diversity:', diversity)

        generated = ''
        sentence = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
        generated += sentence
        print('----- Generating with seed: "' + sentence + '"')
        sys.stdout.write(generated)

        for i in range(400):
            x_pred = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
            for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
                x_pred[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

            preds = model.predict(x_pred, verbose=0)[0]
            next_index = sample(preds, diversity)
            next_char = indices_char[next_index]

            sentence = sentence[1:] + next_char

            sys.stdout.write(next_char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print()

print_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=on_epoch_end)

model.fit(x, y,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=60,
          callbacks=[print_callback])
```

Hope this is what you are looking for, best wishes :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you know about text classification, but in this case you want to predict class based on two inputs instead of one.

If you want to predict text (class) from 2 inputs, you can either train two models, each on each input and then get the prediction from the mean, or concatenate these two inputs into one input prior training, and then predict based on that one input

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually, my problem is how to predict text from a text input.

Comment: If you want to predict text, instead of a particular classes, you could use Seq2Seq RNN. You can think of it as a machine translation problem

Comment: I didn't know about it. I ll definitely research about it. Thank you.